# About dynamically created radio button in c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, dynamic-controls

I'm trying to develop a **Windows 8 Metro app** where i needed to create an arbitrary number of radio buttons, but the Checked event handler is not firing up. 
I read in some post that I've to enable AutoPostBack. 
Please let me know in which namespace it is? Also i found that it is in System.Web.UI.Webcontrols, but i'm unable to include that namespace.. 
I'm using visual studio 2012 ultimate if that helps

```
RadioButton rad=new RadioButton();
            rad.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            rad.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            rad.Margin = new Thickness(1100, x, 0, 0);
            rad.Width = 35;
            rad.Height = 30;
            rad.GroupName = "group1";
            rad.IsEnabled = true;
            rad.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(radbtn);
            gridit.Children.Add(rad[i]);

void radbtn(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        edit_del_tb.Text = "Testing";
    }
```

Comment: where is your code that you tried?

Comment: You clearly haven't searched before asking... googling "autopostback" provides good answers in the first results...

Comment: RadioButton is indeed in System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton, once you've created an instance of that type server side, you can turn its AutoPostBack property to true

Comment: Error 2 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RadioButton' does not contain a definition for 'AutoPostBack' and no extension method<br> 'AutoPostBack' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RadioButton' could be found (are you missing a<br> using directive or an assembly reference?) I'm getting this error

Comment: Based on your error, I'm guessing that you are NOT building a web page.  AutoPostBack is for ASP.NET.

Comment: It's for building a metro app. My problem is the checked event handler is not firing up when i click on radio button

Comment: Please edit your question and add the appropriate tags.

Comment: If rad is a RadioButton, then what is rad[i]???

Comment: Sorry my bad, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

[`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is not in a namespace, it's a property of [`CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sckzx64d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) because a [`RadioButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.aspx) inherits from `CheckBox`.

You also have to ensure that dynamic controls are recreated on every postback with the same ID as before and in `Page_Load` at the latest.

[How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Register the `CheckedChanged` event programmatically:

```
RadioButton btn = new RadioButton();
btn.AutoPostBack = true;
btn.CheckedChanged += this.RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

in this class:

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the reference to the RadioButton that caused the CheckedChanged-event
    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) sender;
}
```

Comment: I've done that. Please see my edit. Sorry i didn't add my code first

Comment: @user1875119: Sorry, i've forgotten to add the `AutoPostback` code in my first version, edited my answer. You need to recreate the dynamic controls on every postback, otherwise the event is not triggered.

Comment: btn.AutoPostBack=true; This is where i'm getting the error, AutoPostBank isn't defined in 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RadioButton'

Comment: @user1875119: I thought that you were using `ASP.NET`.

Comment: No, I'm creating a windows 8 app using xaml and c#

Comment: @user1875119: This is the most important information. That's why tags exist ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more expressive next time.:-p

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a better understanding of what UI technology you are working with.

.NET has many UI frameworks:

- Winforms
- WPF
- Silverlight
- ASP.NET webforms
- ASP.NET MVC
- Windows Phone,
- Windows Store apps.

Most of these UI frameworks have RadioButton controls. They are different classes, and have different properties and behaviors.

Postback is part of the ASP.NET webforms world and **is not what you are looking for**!

*Make sure when you are looking for help to use the correct framework.  (On MSDN  there is usually a dropdown at the top of the page.)*

**Working Example**

Looks like your problem is that you are adding an array of radiobuttons to the Grid, not the RadioButton itself.  Its a bit hard to tell, because you didn't include your XAML or all of your C# code.

Here is some code that does work.

**XAML**

```
 <Grid 
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height='30' />
      <RowDefinition Height='1*' />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name='edit_del_tb' />
    <Grid Grid.Row='1'
          x:Name='gridit'></Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**C# code**

```
   public MainPage() {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
        RadioButton rad = new RadioButton();
        rad.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        rad.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        rad.Margin = new Thickness(100, i * 40, 0, 0);
        rad.Width = 350;
        rad.Height = 30;
        rad.GroupName = "group1";
        rad.IsEnabled = true;
        rad.Content = "Button " + i;
        rad.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(radbtn);
        gridit.Children.Add(rad);
      }

    }
    void radbtn(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      edit_del_tb.Text = (obj as RadioButton).Content.ToString();
    }
```